# How to show regions in shape map using a table with four columns

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I tried to create a shape map, but when I hover on the map, I get region undefined. I have searched the internet for possible solutions, but they do not solve the problem. I have checked use map and filled map visuals from the security settings. I have also checked the shape map visuals in the preview settings, but nothing. I have also attached the data structure of my Excel file in the image below.

[image]

I have downloaded the necessary shape map files, converted them to TopoJOSON format, and uploaded them in Power BI, but still no display.